# Django Custom User Model app level permissions management in admin

Tags: django

I use a custom user model in my django 1.9 project. The model is very similar to the full example given on Django documentation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/). After integrating the model, app level permissions are disabled on the admin. Only the `is_admin` attribute is available. Is there a way to have app level permissions as in the default admin interface when using a custom user model?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution in the meanwhile. In the full example given on the documentation, group permissions are disabled for some reason. Also Group model was unregistered on the example. First of all, I used PermissionsMixin. I kept group model registered and  add 'groups' and 'user_permissions' on the fieldsets of UserAdmin, and they came back.